# Writing - Touch upon

Tags: single-word-requests, writing

I want to write a summary about a reading and a listening passage that both discuss about the same subject and I'm wondering which sounds better; should I keep the word "both", should I place it in the beginning or in the middle? Also is the phrasal verb "touch upon" appropriate?

The reading and the lecture both touch upon the issue of... 
Both the reading and lecture touch upon the issue of...

Do you have any suggestion how to make it sound more eloquently?
Maybe if I start this way: Touching upon the issue of ...., the author of the reading passage suggests that ...., whereas the lecturer suggests ....

Comment: Either is fine (provided you add the second 'the'; choose one of your first two examples; 'make it sound more eloquent / better' (you need an adjective there). 'Do you have any suggestions as to how to make it sound more eloquent?' But that would be writing advice; wrong SE site.

Comment: Thank you very much, sir!